# How to set value of 'a' depending on value of 'b' in mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a table called `thingies` with columns `example11` and `random44`. If the value of `example11` is 123, then I would like the value of `random44` to be set to 456.

This is what I came up with, but obviously it does not work, that's why I need your help (I saw 'when' and 'then' used on some forum, thats why I gave it a shot)

```
UPDATE thingies WHEN example11 = '123' THEN SET random44 = '456'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
UPDATE thingies SET random44 = '456' WHERE example11 = '123'
```

You'd only use THEN inside a [CASE statement (you can read more about them here...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE thingies SET random44 = '456' WHERE example11 = '123'
```

But if random44 and example1 are numerical fields (as opposed to text), you don't need the quotes.

Also be sure to check out the [official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), and [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).